# Custom package names cxf-codegen-plugin

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

Imagine this scenario.

I have a wsdl file with namespace a/b/c and it imports another wsdl whose namespace is m/n/o.
Unfortunately, both of them have same ComplexTypes XYZ defined in them. Now, when I use  cxf-codegen-plugin to generate Java code and use custom package name "com.qsrs.uvw", only one class is retained in the final code that is generated. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Don't define the packagename let cxf-codegen-plugin do the work.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you want to generate package depending on the namespace here is the solution:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>yourWsdl.wsld</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>http://your.namespace/services/=your.package</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>http://your.namespace2/services2/=your.package2</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This `<extraarg>http://your.namespace2/services2/=your.package2</extraarg>` will map your namespace with the package you want.

Comment: thanks for the response. Can you please let me know if it is possible to specify a prefix to all the packages that are generated?

Comment: What do you mean prefix for packages?

Comment: @Paulius..Imagine I allow JibX to respect schema, I want all the package generated to be under a root package jibx.x.y.z. The actual problem is I have a cxf-code-gen plugin generating code using same schema. So effectively I have two classes with same package structure and name. Hence, I want to place all the classes generated by jibx under a different root.

Comment: best solution. almost worried there when it didn't work but it was because of the `/` before the `=`. The pattern is `namespace=desired_package`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `packagenames` configuration, too:

```xml
<wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>yourWsdl.wsld</wsdl>
    <extraargs>
        <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
    </extraargs>
    <packagenames>
        <packagename>http://your.namespace/services/=your.package</packagename>
        <packagename>http://your.namespace2/services2/=your.package2</packagename>
    </packagenames>
</wsdlOption>
```

I use the version `3.5.5` of `cxf-codegen-plugin`