# CXF custom package name

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I'm using the cxf-codegen-plugin to geneare java classes from WSDL. See below for the configuration.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-client</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>src/main/generated</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>...wsdl</wsdl>
                          </packagenames>-->
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-validate</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-xjc-verbose</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>nl.company.gen</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But this solutions is changing package names of generated source under one single package,
I need like package structure as it as based on wsld. Along with custom package.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom package names cxf-codegen-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605379/custom-package-names-cxf-codegen-plugin)

Comment: @McMutton no, because following that solution you have to specifiy a package for each namespace. And there too much namespaces to do that manually.